# Calling functions in Actionscript: "Term is undefined and has no properties"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm writing a genetic fitness program, and I'm currently writing some code that will calculate the 'fitness' value of each organism.

I'm trying to call a function that initializes each genotype;

```
function random_genotype_initialisation():void 
{
    //stuff
}
```

By using the typical method-calling I'm used to in C# and Java;

```
random_genotyoe_initialisation();
```

However this returns the error: "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties."

I've looked elsewhere for help, and I've found suggestions such as declaring a variable and 'calling' that.

```
var rep = replicate_new_generation();
rep.call();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's an undefined value inside your random_genotype_initialisation() function. You are correct, you call a function in as3 same as in java/c/c++/c#/js/etc.

The snippet is a bit wrong because you store the result of the `replcate_new_generation` into `rep`, but that is a void function, so `rep` will be void and therefore not have call():

```
var rep = replicate_new_generation();//rep = void at this point
rep.call();//call does not exist for rep
```

Do you mean ?

```
var rep:Function = replicate_new_generation;
rep.call();
```

Which is same as: `replicate_new_generation();`
If the error is generating within the function perhaps you should post the body 
of the function as well ?

Comment: My mistake, it seems the method I'm trying to call can't simply be called on its own, I have to call another method which contains a call for the method stated above.

Thanks for your answer though! I appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't simply be called on its own" ? A function declaration will not invoke itself. Also, glad this helps, feel free to vote/mark as you see fit :)

Answer (score 0):

C# is VERY similar to AS3, I have no idea what you are trying to do or why your code did not work since you didn't provide a very good example. But you can call functions directly as long as it is accessible just in any normal way.

say, inside a class you have:

```
class Boo {
    private function foo():void {
         trace("bar");
    }

    public function foobar():void {
        foo();
    }
}

class FoobarCaller {
    public function FoobarCaller (){
        var asdf:Boo = new Boo();
        asdf.foobar();
    }
}
```

that works, just as it would in C# or any other "standard coding language. However, without a better question it's impossible to say what it is you have done wrong